# Hadoop Map Reduce: How to create a reduce function for this?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I hit a brick wall. I have the following files I've generated from previous MR functions.

**Product Scores** (I have)

```
0528881469  1.62
0594451647  2.28
0594481813  2.67
0972683275  4.37
1400501466  3.62
```

where column 1 = product_id, and column 2 = product_rating

**Related Products** (I have)

```
0000013714  [0005080789,0005476798,0005476216,0005064341]
0000031852  [B00JHONN1S,B002BZX8Z6,B00D2K1M3O,0000031909]
0000031887  [0000031852,0000031895,0000031909,B00D2K1M3O]
0000031895  [B002BZX8Z6,B00JHONN1S,0000031909,B008F0SU0Y]
0000031909  [B002BZX8Z6,B00JHONN1S,0000031895,B00D2K1M3O]
```

where column 1 = product_id, and column 2 = array of also_bought products

The file I am trying to create now combines both of these files into the following:

**Recommended Products** (I need)

```
0000013714  [<0005080789, 2.34>,<0005476798, 4.58>,<0005476216, 2.32>]
0000031852  [<0005476798, 4.58>,<0005080789, 2.34>,<0005476216, 2.32>]
0000031887  [<0005080789, 2.34>,<0005476798, 4.58>,<0005476216, 2.32>]
0000031895  [<0005476216, 2.32>,<0005476798, 4.58>,<0005080789, 2.34>]
0000031909  [<0005476216, 2.32>,<0005080789, 2.34>,<0005476798, 4.58>]
```

where column 1 = product_id and column 2 = array of tuples of

I'm just totally stuck at the moment, I thought I had a plan for this but it turned out that it was not a very good plan and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a [MapFile](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/MapFile.html). I transformed both the `ProductScores` and `RelatedProducts` data sets into two MapFiles and then made a Java program that pulled information out of these MapFiles when needed.

MapFileWriter

```java
public class MapFileWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Path inputFile = new Path(args[0]);
        Path outputFile = new Path(args[1]);
        Text txtKey = new Text();
        Text txtValue = new Text();
        try {
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            FSDataInputStream inputStream = fs.open(inputFile);
            Writer writer = new Writer(conf, fs, outputFile.toString(), txtKey.getClass(), txtKey.getClass());
            writer.setIndexInterval(1);
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                String strLineInInputFile = inputStream.readLine();
                String[] lstKeyValuePair = strLineInInputFile.split("\\t");
                txtKey.set(lstKeyValuePair[0]);
                txtValue.set(lstKeyValuePair[1]);
                writer.append(txtKey, txtValue);
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MapFileReader

```java
public class MapFileReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs;
        Text txtKey = new Text(args[1]);
        Text txtValue = new Text();
        MapFile.Reader reader;
        try {
            fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
            try {
                reader = new MapFile.Reader(fs, args[0], conf);
                reader.get(txtKey, txtValue);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("The value for Key " + txtKey.toString() + " is " + txtValue.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches based on your size of Product Scores data:

1. If your Product Scores file is not huge, you can load that up in Hadoop Distributed Cache.(Now available in Jobs itself) `Job.addCacheFile()`
   Then, process the Related Products file and fetch the necessary rating in the Reducer and write it out. Quick and dirty. But, if Product Scores is a huge file then probably not the correct way to go about this problem.
2. Reduce side Joins. Various examples available, for eg., refer to this [link](https://jayunit100.blogspot.com/2012/07/hadoop-denormalization-of-many-to-many.html) to get an idea.
3. As you already have defined a schema, you can create hive tables on top of it and get the output using queries. This would save you a lot of time.

   Edit: Moreover, If you already have map-reduce jobs ton create this file, you can add hive jobs, which creates external hive tables on these reducer outputs and then query them.

Comment: I was thinking about using a MapFile to store the product scores and pull key-value pairs into the reducer. (It might be slow). I was also thinking about using a distributed database also. I'll look into Hive to see how I can possibly implement it.

Note: The product scores file is 1.6GB, would that be too large for distributed cache?

Comment: I have used Distributed cache for files close to 2 GB and works fine. More than would not sure about it. if you have the possibility of the products file drastically increasing, using Hive tables would be a feasible approach

Comment: If you already have map-reduce jobs ton create this file, you can add hive jobs, which creates external hive tables on these reducer outputs and then query them.